# Python pandas loop that deletes csv rows until a string appears

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm having trouble to create a code that reads a .csv file row by row and keep deleting the rows until it finds a certain string.
For instance, I want to keep only the rows after "AH":

```
SG 1 2 3

OH 3 3 UI

AH 4 5 5

R3 4 4 4
```

The code should return only:

```
R3 4 4 4
```

Can anyone help me with this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first convert to string by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) and compare. Then 
with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html), [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) is created `mask`. 
Last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df)
    0  1  2   3
0  SG  1  2   3
1  OH  3  3  UI
2  AH  4  5   5
3  R3  4  4   4
4  AH  4  4   4
5  R3  4  4   4

print (df.astype(str) == 'AH')
       0      1      2      3
0  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False
2   True  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False
4   True  False  False  False
5  False  False  False  False

print (((df.astype(str) == 'AH').cumsum().shift() > 0).any(1))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
dtype: bool

print (df[((df.astype(str) == 'AH').cumsum().shift() > 0).any(1)])
    0  1  2  3
3  R3  4  4  4
4  AH  4  4  4
5  R3  4  4  4
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you mean by deleting the rows, or did you mean ignoring the rows. 
This might work for you:

```
import csv

def return_required_row(filename_to_read, filename_to_write ,keyword):
    with open(filename_to_read, 'r')  as fin, open(filename_to_write, 'w') as fout: 
        reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=';')
        writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=';')
        for row in reader:
            if row[0] == keyword:
                # print row
                break
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    return_required_row('Export 3.csv', 'sample.csv','Distance')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This code would work if I only wanted to return the line with that particular string. However, my goal is to definitely  delete all the csv lines above the string

Comment: Fine, you said 'The code should return only:' so I thought of a list - anyways modified the answer- check if it works for you!